# Why is $\exists x \forall y (x+y=0)$ false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

In a textbook example about nested quantifiers, we had $P(x,y): x+y=0, x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. The examples stated the following

1.$\forall x \forall y P(x,y)$ is False, $(3+2 = 0)$

2.$\forall x \exists yP(x,y)$ is Correct ,$x + (-x) = 0$

3.$\exists x \forall yP(x,y)$ is False, $\forall y (c+y=0)$

I cannot fully understand the **third** example however. Where did $c$ came from? And why is $\forall y (c+y=0)$ given as example to prove that it is incorrect? Also, why does it differ so much from $\forall x \exists yP(x,y)$? I appreciate the help!

Comment: 3) says: there is number that is the "inverse" of every number. The counter-example assume that it holds: call it $c$. Then the number $c$ must satisfies the equation $c+y=0$, for every number $y$. Impossible !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just translate it into English. What is the third example saying? There exists an $x$ such that for all $y$, $x+y = 0$. It is saying that for all real numbers $y$, there is an element of the real numbers that "cancels" out $y$.

So, for example, there is an $x$ such that $x+1 = 0$ and $x+2 = 0$. This is, of course, nonsense. We know that it's not true (from your studies with the real numbers blah blah blah).

How does it differ from:

$$\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$$?

Again, look at what's being said in English. It's saying that for each real number $x$, there exists a real number $y$ such that $x+y = 0$. This is saying that every real number has a "negative", so to speak. In formal language, every real number has an additive inverse. The two statements are very different in the **assertions** they are making. The point is that interchanging quantifiers results in different statements entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Order matters. In the third example, there is only one fixed x for all y. Since x is fixed we can say it is equal to some constant, c. In the second example, y is not fixed, but can be chosen for each x. (In this case we choose y = -x). We do not have that luxury in the third example.

Answer (score 1):

The third proposition says that there exist a real $ x_0 $ such that for any real $ y $ , we have $$x_0+y=0$$
observe that $ x_0 $ is fixed and it doesn't
depend on $ y $.

So, the condition $ x_0+y=0$ must be satisfied for all $ y\in \Bbb R $, and in particular for $ y=0$ which  gives $ x_0=0$  and for $ y=-1 $ which gives $ x_0=1$.

This is a contradiction because $ x_0 $ cannot take two different values..

The difference between
$$\forall x \exists y$$
and
$$\exists x \forall y$$
is the fact that in the first, $ y $ depends on $ x $ and in the second $ x $ is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a counterexample situation.  To negate an existential quantifier, you need to prove a universal negation, which you can't do with a counterexample.

The point here is that for any specific number $x=c$, there will be values of $y$ for which $c+y\ne 0$

Comment: The same $x$ is supposed to work for all $y$.